# Пустой бланк при заходе на томкат localhost после развёртывания с IDEA

Tags: java, веб-программирование, tomcat

Всем привет.

Получаю не понятный пустой бланк после удачного развёртвания апликации.

OS:Debian 8

IDE: IDEA Ultra 2016.2

Version:Tomcat 8

В чём может быть проблема? Сталкиваюсь с таким первый раз!

```
Connected to server
[2016-09-06 10:44:27,389] Artifact webapp: Artifact is being deployed,please wait...
[2016-09-06 10:44:27,657] Artifact webapp: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2016-09-06 10:44:27,657] Artifact webapp: Deploy took 269 milliseconds
06-Sep-2016 10:44:37.276 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web    application directory /bin/apache/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/webapps/manager
06-Sep-2016 10:44:37.300 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web   application directory /bin/apache/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/webapps/manager has  finished in 24 ms
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не смотря на то что я получаю blank page..Я получаю ответ от моей апликации! 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Запуская `tomcat` при помощи командной строки, ты запустишь его с дефолтными приложениями. Запуская через `IDEA` ты запускаешь его без них. Дефолтные приложения это обычно `ROOT` (контекст `/`) и `manager` (контекст `/manager`). Лежат они в папке `webapps` домашней директории `tomcat`. Т.е. твой случай - это нормальное поведение.

Comment: Не совсем. Я делаю абсолютно тоже самое на своём лептопе. Там нету такого, запускается всё как положено.
Лептоп linux mint. 
PC debian 8, с которым такая проблема. Не могу найти разницу в струтктуре проекта, всё идентично.
В вопросе скрин с консоли IDEA

Comment: @maks.burkov найди приложение `ROOT` в `webapps` и добавь его с серверу с корневым контекстом.